# I dont understand how a collection is made in my mongodb by someone else

Tags: mongodb

[image: Please see this image]

I have a project hosted on digital ocean with some data.
I have used mongodb and node in backend.
I opened my mongodb compass in the morning and found this, Please can anyone tell me what does this mean ?
thanks.

Comment: This is a fairly common MongoDB hack, directly targeting "open" MongoDB instances (those without security enabled). You can do a web search and find out more about it. You'll also discover that, in all likelihood, even paying the ransom won't get your data back. You'll need to restore from a backup (or recreate your data). And absolutely set up security on your database. Sorry this happened to you. Unfortunately, there's nothing that can be done at this point (and given that this isn't a programming question... off-topic for Stack Overflow).

Comment: Hey thank you for your help, however I haven’t lost any data yet is there any way to recover from this ?

Comment: You need to enable security on your database, then re-create your database(s) and collection(s) and remove the bogus collection. Nothing else can be done, really. This is an automated attack - it just happened to (easily) find your server, connect without credentials, delete your collections, and add a new collection with the ransom document. If you don't enable security, and leave your database publicly accessible, you'll just have this happen again.

Comment: A scammer probably wants money from you.

Comment: Fortunately it didn't happen. And i corrected it on time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use default credentials for your droplet? If you didn't change it, some of default droplets in DigitalOcean are **not protected by password for root access** which may make them vulnerable.

As it says, you got hacked. If the data is not sensitive, just ignore it and recreate all the data in the database, properly protecting your DigitalOcean machine/environment this time.

Comment: Hi, data is not sensitive but it is a lot and will take time to recreate, and does this mean my all data will be gone if i ignore it ?